# React to systemdialog SmsManager

Tags: android, smsmanager

My application sends a text like this:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(NUMBER, null, "sms message", null, null);
```

before sending the user is presented a system-dialog that he has to confirm.

"App would like to send a message to 000"

I would like to react to the case when the user cancels that dialog. Is there a way to do that?